# Why is a global vector of pointers (without objects) in C++ leaking in Valgrind when it won't let me use delete after new in two separated files?

Tags: pointers, memory, vector, global, valgrind

So I have a struct:

```
typedef struct {

    int x = 0;

} Command;
```

and global vectors:

`vector<Command> cmdList = {}; vector<Event*> eventList = {};`

I push_back, erase and clear the vector in another .cpp file.  This gets pushed back into:

`vector<Command> cmdsToExec = {};` inside per Event struct created. I use this to push_back:

`eventList.push_back( new Event() ); eventList[int( eventList.size() ) - 1]->cmdsToExec = cmdList;`

My problem A) these Event*s can't be erased with delete and B) is that Valgrind gives this error while trying to determine the size of the cmdsToExec:

```
==25096==    Invalid read of size 8
==25096==    at 0x113372: std::vector<Command, std::allocator<Command> >::size() const (stl_vector.h:919)
==25096==    by 0x11C1C7: eventHandler::processEvent() (eventHandler.cpp:131)
==25096==    by 0x124590: main (main.cpp:88)
==25096==  Address 0x630a9e0 is 32 bytes inside a block of size 56 free'd
==25096==    at 0x484BB6F: operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==25096==    by 0x11C116: eventHandler::processEvent() (eventHandler.cpp:222)
==25096==    by 0x124590: main (main.cpp:88)
==25096==  Block was alloc'd at
==25096==    at 0x4849013: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==25096==    by 0x11B4A5: eventHandler::createEvent() (eventHandler.cpp:58)
==25096==    by 0x11B412: eventHandler::doState() (eventHandler.cpp:41)
==25096==    by 0x124575: main (main.cpp:83)
```

Ive tracked it to the line:

`while( int( eventList[0]->cmdsToExec.size() ) > 0 ) {`

Im not trying to solve this specific problem, its more about how to properly delete and unallocate a dynamic pointer from a global vector of dynamic pointers. That being said there are no objects (and I want to keep it that way). Will I need a struct deconstructor (no pun intended)? Also I dont believe cmdList vector ever has a memory leak according to this error message, also as Im clearing it all at once.

My thoughts on fixing this are to place both global vectors into my main() function and pass them into the program from there. I thought it would be unnecessary to do this and would slow the program down. Thinking now, I guess it wouldn't.

Comment: There is a problem with the order that you are deleting things. It's hard to say exactly why as you don't give enough information. When exactly are you delete these objects? Can you post a minimal example that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is a problem related to the order of destruction of static/global objects.

C++ guarantees that for a given translation unit (i.e., a cpp source file) then statics/global objects get created in the order that they are defined, and they are destroyed in the reverse order.

C++ gives *no* guarantee between different translation units.

My recommendations are:

1. Avoid statics/globals. Move them to be class members if possible.
2. If you have any dependencies between statics/globals then put them all in the same source file so that you have control over the order of their creation and destruction.